# How to get data from DB of 'testimonials' content type?

Tags: nodes

I have create a content type .i.e "testimonial",

This content type have two fields.

```
[1]field_data_field_testimonial_title
[2]field_data_field_testimonial_image
```

I have insert 3 records from admin, 
Now i want to retrieve all(3) records of "testimonial" content type.

But How?

Comment: How do you want to get them?  Via code?  Make a page with all three?  We need more info on what you are trying to accomplish, and then we can tell you how.

Answer (score 1):

You want to learn how to use the [views module.](https://drupal.org/project/views)

- You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort
  it differently.
- You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to
  sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
- You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain
  type.
- You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display
  articles the way you like.
- You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of
  some particular type.
- You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
- You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable
  Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of
  "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and
  displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
  for that month.

Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some of the obvious uses of Views.

Comment: So, it means i want to use View module for the same?

Comment: Yes use views, to get all the records of your testimonial content type